# How can I configure a keyboard navigation that when called, focuses ONLY on the items displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation function that focuses on each item in an array for each shift + left/right arrow keypress.

```
var summaryList;
   summaryList = [
        'tile1Sm',
        'tile2Sm',
        'tile3Sm',
        'tile1Lg',
        'tile2Lg',
        'tile3Lg',
        ];
```

Navigation Function

```
// Hold reference to the currently focused position
    var currentPosition = 0;

    // Maximum position we can navigate to is the last item in the summary list
    var maxFocusablePosition = summaryList.length - 1;

    // Utility function to focus a given position value
    function focusPosition(position) {
       // console.log("focus position is called");
            $('#' + summaryList[position]).focus() 
            //return summaryList[currentPosition];
            return console.log(summaryList[currentPosition]);
        };
```

**What should happen**: The way the application is set up, there should always be 2 small tiles visually displayed and then 1 large tile visibly  displayed (each item in the array has a 'sm' and 'lg' version). The way the lg tile is selected is  another function that expands the sm tile into a lg tile. Only one version of the tile can be displayed (ex: you can't set focus to both til1sm and tile1lg)

**What currently happens** With the code I provided, the navigation function traverses and sets focus through the whole array (even when a sm/lg tile/item is not displayed). I can't seem to understand how I can set of a configuration where it tests whether or not the lg tile is displayed. If it is displayed, the sm tile should not have focus and ultimately 'skipped' in the aray and instead focus on the lg tile.

Comment: you don't close your array declaration properly

Comment: apologize just corrected that

Comment: Please post complete code or, even better, a fiddle.

Comment: Sure im working on that right now!